# How do I protect myself if a scammer has my name, email, state and birthdate?

Tags: scams

I gave a scammer my first and last name, gmail and birthdate. How can I protect myself from credit card and loan theft?

Comment: I think giving them this information carries a bigger risk of your gmail being hacked than any sort of credit shenanigans.  Even then, as long as your gmail password is NOT a composition of your birthdate and your name, you're probably not really any more vulnerable than you were before.

Comment: Although, maybe review how secure your gmail password really is, and change it if necessary, just to be safe.

Answer (score -2):

Freezing your credit files is probably the best way to protect yourself in this situation.